# Is there a way to use onClick on a `legend` HTML element in React on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mobile

I'm trying to make an expandable `fieldset` of checkboxes for a search. The `onClick` should trigger a state change from true to false, which changes the class on a div.

On desktop this `onClick` works without issue on the `legend` tag. On iOS (firefox and safari) the `onClick`never triggers on this element, but `onClick` will trigger on other unrelated elements in the app on mobile.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Months() {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
    let classes = ["column", expanded ? "showing" : "hiding"];

    return (
        <fieldset className="row">
            <legend onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}>
                    Click to search by time of year
            </legend>
            <div className={classes.join(" ")}>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="jan" name="months" value="1" />
                    <label htmlFor="jan">January</label>
                </div>
  // more months
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="dec" name="months" value="12" />
                    <label htmlFor="dec">December</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    );
}
```

I've tried adding `cursor: pointer` to the css for the element, using `onPointerDown` and `onTouchStart`, and creating an eventHandler function watching for a click on the element. I've also tried adding mobile-friendly clickable tags like `a` and `button` inside the `legend`. Putting tag like `div` or `a` around the legend breaks the legend

```js
// doesn't work
            <legend>
                <button onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}>
                    Click to search by time of year, by default it searches year round
                 </button>
            </legend>

// breaks the legend
            <a onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}>
                <legend>
                    Click to search by time of year, by default it searches year round
                 </legend>
            </a>
```

Moving the click event outside the fieldset works, but it makes the page a little uglier.

```js
// works
    <a onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}>TEST</a>
        <fieldset className="row">
            <legend>
                Click to search by time of year, by default it searches year round
            </legend>
```

So it appears that the `legend` prevents any child tags from being `onClick`-able. Is there a way to force this to work or a work around? I know `legend` is outdated but for what I'm doing I like the look.

Comment: Some other invisible element might be overlapping your target elements in smaller resolution

Comment: I don't know a lot about debugging on mobile, but I don't think this is what's happening. I just commented out everything except this fieldset and I got the same results.